# Where can I view Xcode generated code?

Tags: xcode, ide, code-generation

I work a lot of with the Visual Studio and I'm able to view auto-generated IDs and other stuff, when I'm adding some controls to the form via Designer window.

But, I don't know about XCode possibilities.

I've added some controls to the form and have bind some events to it.
Where does locate the generated code for the UI?
I want to view the source code of the generated code, which was created by the designer window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xCode is different from Visual studio. Visual Studio provides lots of simplicity for development. xCode has it's own way of doing things.

Once you create a View typically you can see the code in associated ViewController class (.m) and header(.h)

Probably you need to have a look at the basics, these guide can help you in detail

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ios-development-guide-part1/ 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/